# Would there be any way to translate this map to work in UIMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit, android-mapview

I am making an app that will display my colleges campus; I want it to have all of the buildings and labels. On my schools website, there is a map made with Googles Map API. Would there be any easy way to get this map (all of the colored buildings/annotations) to work in a UIMapView? Heres the link:

http://www.millersville.edu/directions/

I understand the one on the website is in JavaScript, and UIMakKit uses reverse geocoding; and I have look up numerous similar questions, but nothing could help me with I was looking for.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has a format called [KML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) which expresses the geographic annotations on a map. 
There are a number of possibilities to view such a format on the iPhone, you can start by checking out what this guy did [YouTube Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xo5tPjsFBX4)

Comment: I watched the video but I don't see how this would work. I want to display this map within my map in a UIMapView. Here is a different link to the map that I want to use now: http://www.millersville.edu/~rgriffith/beta/map/

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think "owner" of that map can transform it to a KML file. Then the tutorial shows how to view a KML file on the iPhone.

Comment: The problem is that my University wants to make sure that when the website info is updated, the app will be to. I read there are ways to make basically a wrapper app that loads the Google map in a WebView, but with optimizations: [link](http://blogs.missouristate.edu/web/2009/12/07/going-mobile-extending-a-maps-api-project-to-smart-phones/comment-page-1/#comment-1751). But I am unsure how to go about these "optimizations".